# Как сделать что бы файлы не меняли контрольные суммы после сборки пакета rpm?

Tags: linux, rpm

Собираю rpm пакет с готовым набором файлов, те ничего не компилирую.

В BUILD у меня для примера один каталог  /opt/app/bin/ внутри пара бинарников.
Еще имеется spec файл, вот всё интересное оттуда:

```
    %install
    install -D /opt/app/bin/* %{buildroot}/opt/app/bin

    %files
    %defattr (-,root,root)
    /opt/app
```

Так я его собираю:

```
rpmbuild --quiet -bb /home/builder/rpmbuild/SPECS/app.spec
```

Собирается нормальный рабочий пакет, НО:

Те самые бинарники из BUILD/opt/app/bin/* отличаются по контрольным суммам от тех что в итоге попадают в пакет.
Проверяю с помощью md5sum.
Можно ли как то собрать пакет что бы не менялись контрольные суммы?

Не большое пояснение моей проблемы

```
    #До сборки
[root@localhost 09:17 ~]$ md5sum /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILD/opt/app/bin/*
1769f9383bc63f3d992788a0cd1670bf  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILD/opt/app/bin/binarnik1
e518651aa7cd89b549a4134d3772ce0d  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILD/opt/app/bin/binarnik2
a23eacb150882e41fb0c526b4eae93a8  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILD/opt/app/bin/binarnik3


#После сборки(и в процессе после попадания в BUILDROOT), обратите внимание на первый столбец
[root@localhost 09:17 ~]$ md5sum /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/app-1.4-88.x86_64/opt/app/bin/*
5498380ea56c54ca2d35a27204f19379  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/app-1.4-88.x86_64/opt/app/bin/binarnik1
f9a2c57eb8e66fe2ca6168d26ef88971  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/app-1.4-88.x86_64/opt/app/bin/binarnik2
53579991fc7a2d614cfd25a2ae4eb54b  /home/builder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/app-1.4-88.x86_64/opt/app/bin/binarnik3
```

Comment: сравните их дифф утилитой и посмотрите разницу. А там будет понятно, что это. Может какая то тула добавила/убрала перевод строки в самом конце файла или сделала замену. или это просто переносы строк.

Comment: Пикап вы проверяете контрольные суммы? И в конце концов контрольные суммы чего именно? Потому как RPM умеет сам проверять целостность пакета, а индивидуально файлы могут быть проконтролированы разными видами хеш-функций.

Comment: @0andry Добавил пояснение к основному описанию. Суммы именно у самих файликов внутри пакета.

Comment: а какой смысл делать пересборку, если в проекте ничего не должно меняться?

Comment: @DID Есть просто набор бинарников которые надо превратить в обычный .rpm пакет(и я благополучно превращаю) для удобства. Изменений быть и не должно, но они почему то происходят.

Comment: Ну rpm-файл  представляет из себя `cpio`-архив, сжатый `gz`, `xz` или `zstd`. Вы можете менять файлы как хотите или собрать вручную. А так, может быть утилита пытается собрать delta-пакет, чтобы записать только изменения

Comment: А, вы размер файлов посмотрите, `rpm` скорее всего подписывает каждый файл.

Comment: @0andry Размер действительно немного отличается, причем файлики причем файлики "ДО" немного больше, чем размер файликов "ПОСЛЕ". Сравнивать бинарники каким-нибудь Вин Мерджем дело такое себе, ну видно что в трех строках в начале и в конце байты отличаются.
Интереснее как сделать так что бы этой разницы не было.

Comment: http://livecipher.blogspot.com/2012/06/disable-binary-stripping-in-rpmbuild.html

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это абсолютно то что мне надо. В этом тексте прекрасно всё. Спасибо!
(Я не так часто пользуюсь сайтом, как понимаю что бы закрыть вопрос надо что бы ваше сообщение было в виде ответа, а не в виде комментария. Если это так, может переоформите)